# SCNetworkReachability Errors in PinkelStar App

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am trying to add PinkelStar Sharing function to my own app, I follow every step the instruction says, but it did not turn out to be the way it should be. I am a newer to iPhone development, question might be stupid.

---

Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ButtonTest.app/ButtonTest normal i386
cd /Users/spzhang/Documents/IphoneProject/ButtonTest
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk -L/Users/spzhang/Documents/IphoneProject/ButtonTest/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/spzhang/Documents/IphoneProject/ButtonTest/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/spzhang/Documents/IphoneProject/ButtonTest/../PinkelStar-pinkelstar-iOS-demo-359a5be -filelist /Users/spzhang/Documents/IphoneProject/ButtonTest/build/ButtonTest.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ButtonTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/ButtonTest.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework PinkelStar -o /Users/spzhang/Documents/IphoneProject/ButtonTest/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ButtonTest.app/ButtonTest

Undefined symbols:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[PSReachability startNotifier] in PinkelStar(Reachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[PSReachability currentReachabilityStatus] in PinkelStar(Reachability.o)
      -[PSReachability connectionRequired] in PinkelStar(Reachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
      +[PSReachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in PinkelStar(Reachability.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PSMailViewController in PSMailViewController.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[PSReachability stopNotifier] in PinkelStar(Reachability.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[PSReachability reachabilityWithHostName:] in PinkelStar(Reachability.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PSMailViewController in PSMailViewController.o
      objc-class-ref-to-MFMailComposeViewController in PSMailViewController.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[PSReachability startNotifier] in PinkelStar(Reachability.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Thank you for your help!!
Tony

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not linking all the needed Frameworks into your project. Please take a look at the Readme.mdown that lists all of the frameworks and include them into your project. That will resolve these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Required frameworks may not be added to the project correctly or the path given for the framework in Framework search path may be incorrect.Verify.If you are not adding any private framework then leave Framework search path blank and then try.